# Enviar archivo XML a través de un input hidden

Tags: xml

cómo están?

Quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme con algo que me tiene atascado.

Necesito enviar mediante un input hidden un archivo XML con unos valores.

Alguien tiene idea de como se puede hacer?

Acá muestro mas o menos mi código.

El nombre del archivo que necesito enviar es datos.xml ¿Cómo lo agrego al input hidden de nombre datos?

```
<form action="recepcion.php" method="POST">

        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

        <input type="hidden" name="datos" value=" ">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es usar el mismo input tipo **file** pero oculto es decir algo asi:

```
<input type="file" id="miArchivo" name="miArchivo" style="display:none"/>
```

con esto ya tendrias o enviarias tu archivo oculto dentro de tu form no te olvides de agregar el enctype:

```
<form action="recepcion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="miArchivo" name="miArchivo" style="display:none"/>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Para agregar el archivo a este input lo haces como cualquier input mediante el value:

```
<input type="file" value="c:/miArchivo.xml">
```

espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Diego, `<input type="file" value="c:/miArchivo.xml">` eso no funciona así, si esto fuera posible ¿que evitaría que al entrar a una página cualquiera se robaran info de tu PC? El usuario tiene que voluntariamente hacer clic y seleccionar el archivo, sino, no funciona.